# java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to use getdata

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception, data-driven

I'm getting java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NullPointerException

Below is my code. trying to pass data from excel to a textbox. Please help (I'm calling the below method from another test)

```
public class myclass extends class1
{
 public WebElement single = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='IDSingle']"));
 
 public myclass(ScriptHelper scriptHelper)
{
super(scriptHelper);
if(!driver.getTitle().contains("My Page"))
{
throw new IllegalStateException("My page expected, but not displayed!");
}   
}   

public void mytest()
{
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(11,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
String sng=dataTable.getData("RMSeatPage Data", "Single");
System.out.println(sng);
single.sendKeys(sng);
}
}
```

Comment: Check whether you are using same driver instance in every where 
Pls use driver instance as global variable. nullpointexception happens for this issue

Comment: Thank you @JustinLambert for the help. Shall try your solution and get back :)